# What does the '+' sign mean in a coffee script anonymous function do?

Tags: javascript, coffeescript

I came across this coffee script.

```
y = ... // assume something that would work in the context
d3.svg.line().x((d)-> x(new Date(d.epoch * 1000))).y((d)-> y(+d[info]))
```

I want to know what is the `+` sign mean in that anonymous function at the tail. I tried to find coffee script ref. But I never learned this script, and I have know idea what should I look for.

I use JavaScript, and I want to convert this script into JS.

Comment: + converts to number....

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is the [*unary + (plus)*](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Arithmetic_Operators#Unary_plus_(.2B)) and works just as it does in JavaScript; it coerces the operand to a *number*.

> The unary plus operator precedes its operand and evaluates to its operand but attempts to converts it into a number, if it isn't already .. It can convert string representations of integers and floats, as well as the non-string values true, false, and null .. If it cannot parse a particular value, it will evaluate to NaN.

For Objects, such as Dates, `+obj` is the same as calling `obj.valueOf()`.

It has nothing to do with functions.

Comment: so in that context, that sign is useless...errr~

Comment: @davidshen84 Maybe. It all depends on what `d[info]` can evaluate to.

Comment: I hate the piece of code...the `d[info]` evaluates to a string. The `+` sign is a short cut way to convert it to a numerical value...:(